# How to manually open a file that Python is writing in simultaneously?

Tags: python, xlsx, file-writing

I have a python code which performs some calculations and then writes the output to an excel sheet as follows-

```
#  import the necessary packages
import numpy as np
import argparse
import time
import cv2
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, datetime

filename = r'PathToDirectory\Data.xlsx'

def append_df_to_excel(filename, df, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=None,
                       truncate_sheet=False, 
                       **to_excel_kwargs):

    # ignore [engine] parameter if it was passed
    if 'engine' in to_excel_kwargs:
        to_excel_kwargs.pop('engine')

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl')

    # Python 2.x: define [FileNotFoundError] exception if it doesn't exist 
    try:
        FileNotFoundError
    except NameError:
        FileNotFoundError = IOError

    try:
        # try to open an existing workbook
        writer.book = load_workbook(filename)

        # get the last row in the existing Excel sheet
        # if it was not specified explicitly
        if startrow is None and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
            startrow = writer.book[sheet_name].max_row

        # truncate sheet
        if truncate_sheet and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
            # index of [sheet_name] sheet
            idx = writer.book.sheetnames.index(sheet_name)
            # remove [sheet_name]
            writer.book.remove(writer.book.worksheets[idx])
            # create an empty sheet [sheet_name] using old index
            writer.book.create_sheet(sheet_name, idx)

        # copy existing sheets
        writer.sheets = {ws.title:ws for ws in writer.book.worksheets}
    except FileNotFoundError:
        # file does not exist yet, we will create it
        pass

    if startrow is None:
        startrow = 0

    # write out the new sheet
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, startrow=startrow, **to_excel_kwargs, header = False, index=False)

    # save the workbook
    writer.save()


while(True):

#    --------------------------------------------------------------
#    -----------REST OF THE CODE AND COMPUTATION HERE--------------
#    --------------------------------------------------------------

    today = date.today()
    today = today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    now = datetime.now()
    now = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    rec_classes = list(set(classIDs))
    for counting in range(len(rec_classes)):
        my_label = LABELS[rec_classes[counting]]
        my_count = classIDs.count(rec_classes[counting])
        data_dict = ({'today_date' : [today], 'now_time' : [now], 'animal_class' : [my_label], 'animal_count' : my_count})
        df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
        append_df_to_excel(filename, df)
```

The code works fine if I want to write to an excel sheet, and after the code has run, I can open the file and all the content appears perfectly.

The problem is that I want to open the excel file while it is running. I want to see the rows being added and data being appended as the code runs. However, whenever I open the excel file while the code is running, I get a 'Permission Denied' error, and the code stops.
I have tried solving it using *except OSError pass* but it did not help.

Is there anything that can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you two possible ways:

- To write with prints on the the terminal the data you are inserting, or
- To use Python's [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) library, which can be used to log the data in a file and to have a complete vision of what's going on. You can set format, level of importance of logging, handlers... it's an awesome tool, also for other usages.

Comment: That helped. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no straightforward way to have Excel dynamically update its display of a changing file. It's loaded from disk into memory once, and then Excel ignores the disk file.

(If you wrote an Excel macro which revisited the file periodically, maybe you could pull this off. But friends don't let friends use Excel anyway.)